Computing the vibrational frequencies with Newton's mechanics
I need to implement the computation of vibrational frequencies of molecules in RRHO approximation. I have already coded this computation - the Hessian matrix is recounted with my program to mass-weighted coordinates and diagonalized. However sometimes my diagonalization algorithm (Jacobi) crashes. And I thought that it can be of some use for me, if I implement the frequencies computation via classical mechanics (I suppose, the Newtons's mechanics is often useful for better understanding the quantum mechanics).
I remember that I had read somewhere, that for the harmonic approximation, the results produced by the Newton's and quantum mechanics are equal. Is that true? If yes, the next question is how to compute the vibrational frequencies with the Newton's mechanics. I have the following idea: I will implement a molecular dynamics computation, and all atoms in my molecule will firstly get some random velocities, then they will oscillate and the oscillation will be averaged, and maybe a Fourier transformation will be performed for extracting the frequencies from the atomic motions data. Is this idea correct?
